Markdown links in Telegram bot don't behave as expected
I am making a Telegram bot. User asks for a board game, and bot answers with an image of setup for it. It works just fine with straight typing the name of the game, but I also want to list all available games in the database with /list command. Currently it works fine, but I want all the games names to be clickable, so user can find a game in this list, click it and receive an image, but nothing happens when user clicks the link.
I've tried to do it with "t.me/meeple_house_bot/game?name={game}" link for each game in list, and then handle it with check "startswith('/game?name=')". I guess that there are no ways to do what I expect, but maybe there are a way to do it.
def list_handler(chat_id):
games = get_all_games()
if games:
    games_list = '\n'.join([f'[{game}](t.me/MY_BOT_NAME/game?name={game})' for game in games])
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f"Available setups:\n{games_list}", parse_mode='Markdown')
else:
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Unfortunately, there are no game setups at the moment.")

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.startswith('/game?name='))
def inline_game_handler(message):
    game_name = message.text[len('/game?name='):]
    matches = get_photo_path(game_name)
    if matches:
        for game_name, photo_path in matches:
            if os.path.exists(photo_path):
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(photo_path, 'rb'), caption=game_name)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                                 f"I'm sorry, but I can't find a setup for {game_name}. Make sure that you typed the name of the game correctly.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "I'm sorry, but I can't find a setup for this game. Make sure that you typed the name of the game correctly.")


there are indent errors in your code, could you correct them?
